# How to remove a package from Pypi

Tags: python, pypi

How do I remove a package from Pypi?

I uploaded a package to Pypi several months ago.  The package is now obsolete and I'd like to formally remove it.  I cannot find any documentation on how to *remove* my package.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

- Login.
- Go to your packages.
- Check the "remove" checkbox for the particular package.
- Click "Remove" button.

Comment: Ok, follow-up question...how do I know which "user" registered it?

Comment: @Rico the username is shown at the bottom of the package page as "Package Index Owner".

Comment: Thank you, it looks like there is confusion about users in Pypi.  I'll have to take more steps to get to my solution.

Comment: Any idea if this still exists? I see that PyPi has added a "yank" option, but can't tell (without registering), if there's still a delete-package option. This has become an issue with package-managers, after the whole `npm` "left-pad" issue.

Comment: Ah, found that I do have a login there - and just checked, yes, "delete" is still an option for packages.

Answer (score 25):

### New PYPI Website

[image]

1. Login to pypi.org
2. Go to releases
3. Click `delete` on options dropdown
4. Enter the version number confirm
5. Click `Delete Release` to delete the release.

---

### original answer

Login in to [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/), select the required package from `Your packages`

### To delete only a version of the package.

select `Remove?` check box on the individual package version that you want to delete, and click remove.

> [image]

### To delete the package completely

Scroll down until you see the red box saying Do **NOT** use this button and click Remove this project completely and on the next page, confirm your action. **Don't forget that, there is no undo option**.

> [image]

Comment: I don't see this list when I login: just a list of release names with no checkboxes or links.

Comment: This is dangerous and outdated. The new pypi.org does not work like that. A better way is to deprecate the old package (see my answer)

Comment: @DimitriMerejkowsky deprecation is another story and deletion is another story.  This question is specifically about deletion.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a really good idea, because all users of the previous package will see their install fails.

If you want to deprecate a package, what you can do is publish a last release with a README pointing to the new package. I did that for [python-cli-ui](https://pypi.org/project/python-cli-ui/), which is replaced by `cli-ui`

If you want to get fancy you can also:

- Add a warning printed when `setup.py` is run
- or at import time
- or replace the package by a dummy one that depends on the new name.

Comment: You, sir, vastly overestimate the number of users of my previous packages. :) (Seriously though don't delete packages that people use)