# Remove packages from local pypi index

Tags: setuptools, pypi, python-packaging, devpi, pypiserver

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403387/how-to-remove-a-package-from-pypi) with one exception. I want to remove a few specific versions of the package from our local pypi index, which I had uploaded with the following command in the past.

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r <index_name>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

As an addenum from @jan-vlcinsky's answer

## Removing from [`pypiserver`](https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver)

Using `curl` for instance:

```
curl --form ":action=remove_pkg" --form "name=<package_name>" --form "version=<version>" <pypiserver_url>
```

Answer (score 12):

Removing packages from local pypi index **depends on type of pypi index you use**.

## removing package from `devpi` index

`devpi` allows [removing packages](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/userman/devpi_packages.html#removing-a-release-file-or-project) only from so called volatile indexes. Non-volatile are "release like" indexes and removing from them is not allowed (as you would surprise users depending on released package).

E.g. for package `pysober` version 0.2.0:

```
$ devpi remove -y pysober==0.2.0
```

## removing package from public pypi

is described in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403387/how-to-remove-a-package-from-pypi) you already refered to.

## removing package from other indexes

Can vary, but in many cases you can manually delete the files (with proper care).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [pypiserver](https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/) and had to remove a bad package so I just SSH'd in and removed the bad packages and restarted the service.

The commands were roughly:

```
ssh root@pypiserver
cd ~pypiserver/pypiserver/packages
rm bad-package*
systemctl restart pypiserver.service
```

That seemed to work fine for me, and you can just remove what you need using standard shell commands. Just be sure to restart the process so it refreshes its index.