# How to delete python package from pypi-type repository using command line?

Tags: python, api, artifactory, pypi, twine

I need to delete a python package from a private python package index (a.k.a. repository) using the command line. This repo is on artifactory, but I am not able to use the artifactory portal UI to do this.

The package was originally uploaded using `twine`. However, it looks like there is no `delete` functionality in twine.

Twine was able to succeed at the upload despite being agnostic of it being an artifactory repo... so I assume there is some kind of standardized pypi-type api...?

(This question is similar but different to [How to remove a package from Pypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403387/how-to-remove-a-package-from-pypi) , because it is asking specifically about a private repo and asking specifically about a CLI solution)

Comment: Warehouse (the backend behind the current PyPI.org) doesn't have any [API](https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/index.html) to delete packages. Any compatible implementation probably doesn't have it either.

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned that the package has been uploaded to the Artifactory's repository using "twine", I assume the package currently exists in a PyPI local repository of the Artifactory instance.

Since you are looking for an option to delete this artifact from the repository via the command line, please check if this [REST API call to delete the artifact](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteItem) is an option for you.

I am sharing a sample command here for your reference.

```
curl -u <USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> -X DELETE "http://ARTIFACTORY_HOST:ARTIFACTORY_PORT/artifactory/admin-pypi-remote-cache/bd/"
```

admin-pypi-remote is my repository name and bd is the target folder/package of the deletion task.

Comment: Unfortunately, artifactory's response is `405 method not allowed`

Comment: "HTTP 405" could have occurred either due to an incorrect repository path or if the method being used/expected is distinct. Can you please check it?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using a local pypi server, to delete an uploaded artifact use the following command:

```
curl -u <USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> --form ":action=remove_pkg" --form "name=<PACKAGE_NAME>" --form "version=<VERSION>" <PYPI_SERVER_URL>
```

Comment: Which software (server implementation) does this answer refer to? Any link to documentation or reference?

Comment: I think that's aimed at pypiserver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57795279