# Re-uploading a deleted PyPi project with a new version number

Tags: python, package, pypi

I'm new to creating packages on PyPi, I have a package that I made an error with on the first version upload. In attempting to correct this while using the same version number, I ended up deleting the package all together to start over [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43603029/943773) (I now know you still can't re-use version numbers).

I have now uploaded the package again with `twine` with a new version number, which appears to have gone fine, but it doesn't showing up in a search on PyPi. It does show on my account on the new `pypi.org` site, but the link is broken.

What have I done?! Is it not allowed to create a project with a previously used project name, despite it now having been removed from PyPi?

Considering I created it, I would think I could add the project again to PyPi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first upload I made with an increment to the version number `0.2`, succeeded but did not display.

I then made another trivial change and increment to the version `0.3`, which has uploaded and displays correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

just increase the version number in setup.py file and also delete the folder generated by sdist i.e dist and your_package_name.egg-info