# How to protect PyPI package from being deleted

Tags: python, pypi

It seems deleting a PyPI package is possible - [How to remove a package from Pypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403387/how-to-remove-a-package-from-pypi)

This can cause problems if multiple team members have access to PyPI account holding the PyPI package and permissions. A person can accidentally delete a package if a person don't know dependent packages using the specific versions of a particular package.

Is it possible to block deletion of certain PyPI packages or send a notification if someone performs this sort of operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyPI has two distinct roles for project collaborators:

> **Maintainer**:
> Can upload releases for a package. Cannot add collaborators. Cannot delete files, releases, or the project.
>
> **Owner**:
> Can upload releases. Can add other collaborators. Can delete files, releases, or the entire project.

You can prevent your project from being accidentally deleted by giving it a single "owner", and making all other collaborators "maintainers".

With regards to notifications, this isn't currently possible, [but would make a great feature request](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/new?template=feature-request.md).

Comment: thanks Dustin. opened a feature request https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/5714?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container