# Execute post installation task with pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, pypi, python-wheel

My Project Tree Structure

```
.
├── example.gif
├── funmotd
│   ├── config.json
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── quotes_db.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

`setup.py`(Removed some code in order to have less code)

```
import sys
import os
import setuptools
from setuptools.command.install import install

class PostInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        mode = 0o666
        bashrc_file = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), ".bashrc")
        install.run(self)
        # Added CLI to .bashrc
        # Change "config.json" file permission


setuptools.setup(
      ...
      entry_points={'console_scripts': ['funmotd = funmotd:main']},
      package_dir={'funmotd': 'funmotd/'},
      package_data={'funmotd': ['config.json'], },
      include_package_data=True,
      python_requires=">=3.4",
      cmdclass={'install': PostInstall, },
      ...      
)
```

The `PostInstall` is executing fine when I run `python3 setup.py install`. So, uploaded to `Pypi` like below(From [this doc](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/?highlight=pypirc#id78))

```
$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
# Created "dist", "funmotd.egg-info" and "build" dirs
$ twine upload dist/*
```

But when I run `pip install funmotd`, `PostInstall` is **NOT** executing, I see that `dist/*` is like static compiled stuff.
Is there any trick to run post installation tasks when I run `pip install funmotd`. Or how to make `setup.py` execute at `pip`.

I Followed below questions, didn't get solution what I need

- [Post-install script with Python setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools)
- [Run custom task when call `pip install`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853058/run-custom-task-when-call-pip-install)

**PS:** I don't want users to clone repo and run `python setup.py install`. Want to make it simple `pip install funmotd`

**UDPATE1**

Seems there is already [issue on github](https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/64) which is long thread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pip` doesn't run `setup.py` from a wheel hence you cannot run any post-installation code from `setup.py` in a wheel.

`setup.py` is used to build wheels or used during installation of source distribution (sdist). So if you want post-installation script stop uploading wheels to PyPI, only release source distribution (`python3 setup.py sdist`). Then `pip install funmotd` will run code from `setup.py`.

Comment: Even when uploading a sdist, `pip install funmotd` with a modern version of pip will call `setup.py bdist_wheel` and then install the wheel. This should still work since `bdist_wheel` invokes `install`, but it will be pre-install rather than post-install

Comment: @phd "only release source distribution" means clone from repo and run? or any other way? didn't get it.

Comment: @Veerendra It means running `python3 setup.py sdist` (and *not* `bdist_wheel`) followed by `twine upload dist/*`

Comment: Note that you will first need to delete any `.whl` files from the `dist` folder, [remove the uploaded .whl files from PyPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403387/how-to-remove-a-package-from-pypi) and even use `pip install --no-cache-dir funmotd` whenever you try installing it again to avoid any wheels that may be cached on your system. (Or, better yet, just bump the version number and avoid all of this).

Comment: thanks. I uploaded old files too with curiosity. I messed up a release. lol

Answer (score -2):

You need to invoke the parent run, first, before executing the rest of your `PostInstall`, could you try:

```
class PostInstall(install):
def run(self):
    install.run(self)
    mode = 0o666
    bashrc_file = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), ".bashrc")
    # Added CLI to .bashrc
    # Change "config.json" file permission
```

This hopefully will solve the problem - I've had problems with something very similar myself, works locally, but not through pip.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just checked. Didn't work that.

Comment: hmmm, do you get any warnings at all?

Comment: `pip install -v ...`