# In setup.py, how to run a system command before any pip install?

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I am creating a Python package with `setup.py`, and I need to run certain shell commands *before* pip attempts to install dependencies.  In fact, I need these commands to run *before* setuptools makes network calls to PyPI.

(The nitty gritty context is that the system installing this package has an internet gateway which requires a certificate to be installed.  I need to apply this system change before setuptools reaches out to the internet)

I'm aware of `cmdclass` -- do those commands run *before* the `install_requires` stage?

Comment: Hint: [no way for a wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495693/7976758), will work only for a sdist. And for a sdist you can write your `setup.py` in any way; you can run your commands before `setup()` is called at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run arbitrary commands at install time (for the [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495693/7976758) linked to by *phd* in a [comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65130573/in-setup-py-how-to-run-a-system-command-before-any-pip-install#comment115147225_65130573)).

Maybe there are tricks to make it possible, but they are bad practice and not even worth the trouble.

What I would rather recommend to do is just clearly document the pre-installation steps, and maybe write yourself a shell script (or Python script) that wraps the custom pre-install commands and the actual installation command.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
os.system('cmd /c "Your Command Prompt Command"')
```

write this code to setup.py file before pip install code