# Python setup.py not running post installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pip, setup.py

I have a Python project (let's call it Project A) which contains a setup.py file as following:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_namespace_packages
from setuptools.command.develop import develop
from setuptools.command.install import install


def post_installation():
    import nltk
    nltk.download('punkt')
    nltk.download('wordnet')
    nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')


class PostDevelopCommand(develop):
    """Post-installation for development mode."""

    def run(self):
        develop.run(self)
        post_installation()


class PostInstallCommand(install):
    """Post-installation for installation mode."""

    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        post_installation()


# Setup script
setup(
    name='my-project-a',
    version='1.2.3',
    description='My project A',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    packages=find_namespace_packages(exclude=['tests', 'tests.*']),
    install_requires=list(open('requirements.txt')),
    test_suite='tests',
    cmdclass={
        'develop': PostDevelopCommand,
        'install': PostInstallCommand
    }
)
```

And then, I used twine to deploy it to AWS Code Artifact in a GitHub action:

```
  - name: "Publish to AWS CodeArtifact"
        if: env.BUMPED == 'TRUE'
        run: |
          python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
          twine upload --repository codeartifact dist/*
```

And then, I added this project as a dependency to another project (Let's call it ProjectB) in requirements.txt.
The problem is that, when I install all dependencies in requirements.txt at ProjectB, the Post installation from ProjectA is not being executed in ProjectB, which leads the code to crash, because NLTK modules were not installed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495693/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331693/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22post-install+script%22