# Run a shell script during pip install

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, setup.py, python-wheel

I have published a PyPI package which requires some additional Apt packages and so I have a `setup.sh` in my Github repository which I want to execute along with the installation process of `pip install mypackage` (i.e, whenever a user runs `pip install mypackage` it should run the shell script during the process of installation.)

I made my `setup.py` to use the cmdclass parameter like this

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install
import subprocess
import codecs 
import os

class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        subprocess.check_call("bash setup.sh", shell=True)
        install.run(self)

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()


setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'install': CustomInstall},   install_requires=requirements,
    ...
)
```

When I normally build it with `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` the `Custominstall` class runs fine but during pip installation it ignores the `Custominstall` class.

Finally I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495087/execute-post-installation-task-with-pip) stackoverflow thread from where I learnt that I only need to run `python setup.py sdist` which I did and got a tar.gz file in the `dist` folder but when I go to install that tar.gz file with pip install, I am getting

```
with open('requirements.txt') as f:

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the path not correct? The requirements file is in my repository's parent folder (not inside any other folder)

Comment: "The requirements file is in my repository's parent folder (not inside any other folder)" - but what do you see **in the archive**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because your `setup.py` depends on `requirements.txt` but you're not packaging `requirements.txt` in your distribution. If you open your `.tar.gz`, you won't find your `requirements.txt` file. To fix this, create a `MANIFEST.in` file with the contents:

```
include requirements.txt
```

And add `include_package_data=True` to your `setup` call.

You'll need to add any other non-python files you want to include in your `.tar.gz` distribution, such as your `setup.sh` script as well.

When you build your source distribution with these changes, you'll see that `requirements.txt` is now included in the contents of your build distribution.

Alternatively, you can also use the `package_data` keyword in `setup` for this (or `[options.package_data]` in `setup.cfg`). See: [this link](https://jwodder.github.io/kbits/posts/pypkg-data/) for more in depth explanation.

---

Generally speaking though, it's not a good idea to run shell scripts or install system packages as part of your `setup.py`. It will make your package harder to use, not easier.

If your package depends on *Python dependencies* use `install_requires` instead.

Comment: I have been struggling for days while the solution was so simple . Thanks a lot. Now pip install works fine and it can locate all the required files. I understand your suggestion but i have no option i have to rely on those system packages as my python script is relies on those packages entirely like dialog for gui, ffmpeg, termux-api etc.. You may have a look at my [repository](https://github.com/ayusc/termux-sriparna)

Comment: Usually, you would leave it up to the user to ensure they have the right system packages installed. You can raise a helpful error if your external dependencies are not found like `if not shutil.which('ffmpeg'): raise EnvironmentError("ffmpeg is not installed, please install it e.g., with 'apt install ffmpeg'")` or something like that. Plenty of popular Python libraries depend on system packages -- I guarantee none of them are installing those dependencies for you! Alternatively, you could consider making a conda package or your own debian package to install everything @AyusChatterjee

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that the `pip` process runs in whichever directory the invoking user happens to be in. Perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

The fix for that is [How do I get the path and name of the python file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-python-file-that-is-currently-executing) -- basically, examine `__file__` and derive the directory you want to access from that.

However, the premise of your question seems deeply flawed. You should declare dependencies on whichever Python packages you depend on, and let `pip` take it from there; or else, create a Debian package and then declare all your dependencies in terms of other Debian packages. (You can do both, of course. Certainly in the latter case you should probably also do the former, so that your package can be installed on non-Debian platforms.)

You have not told us which packages yours will depend on, so we can only phrase this in the broadest terms. Let's say your package depends on `requests` and `beautifulsoup4`. Then your `setup.py` should declare these dependencies:

```
setup(
   ...
   install_requires=["requests", "beautifulsoup4"],
   ...
)
```

For convenience, you can *also* declare these in `requirements.txt`, but this file has no formal role in Python packaging. Your dependencies *need* to be declared in `setup.py` (or for modern packages, definitely prefer `pyproject.toml` or `setup.cfg`).

If some of these dependencies can be fulfilled via the OS package manager, providing another installation mechanism for convenience is strictly optional, but a nice add-on. Your package script should not depend on this (but perhaps vice versa).

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get install -y python3-requests python3-bs4
```

(Perhaps notice also how the Debian packages typically have different names than the corresponding Python packages. This is a nuisance, but basically unavoidable.)

Comment: I used a small workaround to print the files under the directories with ```script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        dir_contents = os.listdir(script_dir)

        print("Contents of the directory:")
        for item in dir_contents:
            print(item)``` and i see that the requirements.py and setup.py are not there. The contents of the directory were : ```LICENSE
  PKG-INFO
  README.md
  setup.cfg
  setup.py
  mypackage
  mypackage.egg-info
  build```

Comment: Ok i found a partial solution based on what you said i will put the pip requirements in install_requires = [] and what I did is moved the setup.sh script to mypackage/setup.sh and used package_data parameter in setup() ```package_data={'mypackage': ['setup.sh']},
    include_package_data=True,``` and modified my CustomIntall class as ```class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        setup_sh= script_dir+"/mypackage/setup.sh"
        os.system(f"bash {setup_sh}")
        install.run(self)```

Comment: It's weird that it's using apt instead of pkg where as [my script](https://pastebin.com/2R92ppq7) has used pkg everywhere.```/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-req-build-ky2zym9d/setup.py
  No mirror or mirror group selected. You might want to select one by running 'termux-change-repo'
  Checking availability of current mirror:
  [*] https://termux.astra.in.ua/apt/termux-main: ok

  WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

  Hit:1 https://termux.astra.in.ua/apt/termux-main stable InRelease
  Reading package lists...
...... ...... ...... ```