# How to completely remove a package from PyPI or TestPyPI?

Tags: python, package, release, pypi, testpypi

I could remove all releases of my package `example_package_superkai` but could not remove the package itself from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) or [TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/) as shown below:

[image]

Or:

[image]

Actually, [How to remove a package from Pypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403387/how-to-remove-a-package-from-pypi) doesn't have such answers.

So, how can I completely remove a package from `PyPI` or `TestPyPI`?

Comment: You appear to have removed the *package*, as there are no releases. The PyPI *index entry* is another matter. I don't believe you can (trivially) have it removed, because doing so opens the door for another, possibly malicious, user to upload a package with your old name that unsuspecting users may install, unaware they are no longer getting *your* former package. PEP 541 address the mechanism by which a package name *can* be transferred to another user, but until that transfer happens, your package entry remains.

Comment: (TestPyPI obviously has different use cases, and I believe that while there is no mechanism for *you* to remove a package, abandoned names *can* be pruned by the administrators eventually.)

Comment: Related: https://discuss.python.org/t/stop-allowing-deleting-things-from-pypi/17227 -- https://discuss.python.org/t/is-pep-541-still-the-correct-solution/27436 -- https://discuss.python.org/t/pypi-policy-on-handing-over-protected-standard-library-names-to-third-party-maintainers/27143